# How to close a excel if it is opening when accessing using JAVA and APACHE-POI 3.6?`

Tags: java, apache-poi

We are developing application in JAVA AND using APACHE POI 3.6 for accessing Ms-Excel files. Suppose,my Excel file is opening, when running my program, then it raising the error and program terminated.So, First i want to check that whether my excel is opened or not.If it is opening, then i want to close my excel file and then open and read that file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POI does not run Excel at all. It is independent code that opens your excel file and interprets the contents. There is no straightforward way for you java code to communicate with Excel and check to see if it is running. You can look into Java/COM bridges for complex mechanisms for trying to coordinate.

Comment: bmargulies,Actually, i want to check If the excel file is opened or not(Assume,The file is opened by user manually. is this any way in JAVA to check this using FILE?

Comment: I don't know. It might be that Excel creates an extra file next to it or does something else you can see from Java, but I'm not in the know.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you're going to be able to do from within Java is to check if someone has the file locked for editing using the `canWrite()` method of the `File` class.

You're not going to be able to force the user to close the excel file though.  If the application has a GUI you could post a message to the user requesting they close the file manually.